# LightDM shows a black screen in my Arch Guest VM

Tags: arch-linux, gdm, lightdm

I'm trying to get LightDM to work but for some reason it just shows up a black screen when I get to the user selection screen, GDM works fine though.

I followed the ArchWiki doc and it's strange since it didn't involve any complex configuration:

1. Installed lightdm from yaourt (no errors)
2. On `/etc/inittap` changed `d:3:initdefault:` to `d:5:initdefault:` and `x:5:respawn:/usr/sbin/gdm -nodaemon` to `x:5:respawn:/usr/sbin/lightdm >& /dev/null`

Not sure if it's something related to virtualbox or the actual install.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>&/dev/null` is bash syntax. If you have ash and not bash as `/bin/sh` (I don't know which is the default on Arch), you need to write it the portable way: `>/dev/null 2>/dev/null` or `2>&1 >/dev/null`.

Check the system logs (`ls -ltr /var/log`, look at the recently modified files after you modify `/etc/inittab`). I might have guessed the problem wrong; the logs are likely to have enough information to find what's really going wrong.